# Firebird PHP generator for auto increment

Tags: php, generator, firebird

I have a key ID which would be an auto-incremented unique ID for a Firebird database, and I have a generator made in firebird, already working perfectly, and I want to write the ID in the db for new records. So basically I want to get the correct value with this incrementer generator, but I don't know how to call. PRODUCT_SORSZAM is the generator.

```
$q = ibase_query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_SORSZAM");
echo $q;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following to get next generator value:

```
SELECT GEN_ID(PRODUCT_SORSZAM,1) FROM RDB$DATABASE; Or 
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR PRODUCT_SORSZAM FROM RDB$DATABASE;
```

I assume that PRODUCT_SORSZAM is name of generator, not the name of table.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this kind of thing is to use a trigger to populate the ID field on the "target" table, and then use RETURNING on the INSERT query, like this:

Trigger (let's assume TNAME is the table with the target ID field, and TNAME_GEN_ID is the generator):

```
CREATE TRIGGER TNAME_INSERT FOR TNAME ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0 AS
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN NEW.ID = GEN_ID(TNAME_GEN_ID, 1);
END
```

And then the insert query would be something like:

```
INSERT INTO TNAME (FIELD_1, FIELD_2, ...) VALUES (VALUE_1, VALUE_2, ...)
RETURNING ID
```

This only works in Firebird 2.0  or higher(with "VALUES") or, if you want to use a singleton select as the source of values for the insert, Firebird 2.1 or higher. See also [`INSERT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-dml-insert.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
field1 integer not null,
field2 char(10),
PRIMARY KEY (field1)
);

CREATE GENERATOR gen_test_id;
inserting values:

INSERT INTO test (field1, field2) VALUES (gen_id(gen_test_id, 1), 'testme');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE test ( field1 integer not null, field2 char(10), PRIMARY KEY (field1) );

CREATE GENERATOR gen_test_id; inserting values:

INSERT INTO test (field1, field2) VALUES (gen_id(gen_test_id, 1), 'testme');
```

just a thought :)

Comment: Why are you repeating someone else's answer?